# How can I conditionally make an argument optional for a function in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I wrote a small script to generate all possible values from i18n templates into a TypeScript file to type-check my usages of the i18n function. I am struggling to figure out how to get TypeScript to play nice with strings that do not take any parameters in.

This is my current translation function definition:

```js
import { I18nStrings } from "./i18nStrings";

export type CheckedTFunction = <TKey extends keyof I18nStrings>(
  key: TKey,
  options: I18nStrings[TKey]
) => string;
```

My `i18nStrings.ts` file looks like this (Small snippet for brevity, the real file is about 2500 lines long):

```js
type I18nArg = string | number;
export type I18nStrings = {
"common:abbreviatedMonths.april": never,
"common:abbreviatedMonths.august": never,
"common:buttons.filtersApplied": { "count": I18nArg,  }, 
// ...
};
```

I incorrectly assumed that typing the args as `never` would allow TypeScript to be smart enough to figure out that the second parameter of the translation function should not be provided at all but it isn't the case: Linting (with `tsc --build`) my TypeScript files is raising errors for translation strings that don't take parameters, it expects the options parameter to be of `any` type.

Is what I am trying to do not possible? I am running TypeScript 4.2.3 at the moment.

Bonus points:

Linting does check that parameters are either strings or numbers with the right keys, but VS Code just reports the `options` argument as `any`. Is there something I can do to make VS Code smarter about this?

Edit:
Based on @kaya3 's answer, this is what made it work:

```js
export type CheckedTFunction = {
  <K extends KeysWithOptions>(key: K, options: I18nStrings[K]): string;
  <K extends KeysWithoutOptions>(key: K): string;
};
```

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear for me what You want to achieve. Please provide some example of what you expect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a required argument of type `never`, that means your function can never be called.

What you want can be achieved with [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads): have two overload signatures, one for the keys which require options, and one for the keys that don't take options. Here's a proof of concept:

```
type OptionTypes = {
    foo: {a: string},
    bar: {x: number, y: number},
    baz: never,
    qux: never,
}

type KeysWithoutOptions = {[K in keyof OptionTypes]: OptionTypes[K] extends never ? K : never}[keyof OptionTypes]
type KeysWithOptions = Exclude<keyof OptionTypes, KeysWithoutOptions>

function test<K extends KeysWithOptions>(key: K, options: OptionTypes[K]): void;
function test<K extends KeysWithoutOptions>(key: K): void;
function test<K extends keyof OptionTypes>(key: K, options?: OptionTypes[K]): void {
    console.log(key, options);
}
```

Tests:

```
// OK
test('foo', {a: 'foo'});

// error: Argument of type '{ x: number; y: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ a: string; }'.
test('foo', {x: 1, y: 2});

// error: Argument of type '"foo"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'KeysWithoutOptions'.
test('foo');

// OK
test('baz');

// error: Argument of type '"baz"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'KeysWithOptions'.
test('baz', {a: 'qux'});
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AKuCBnKBeKA3gLABQU5UAZkkgFyECG9WwATgigOYC+ANKRSgAjBq3oEAHvRQBXALZCIrXlBDT5i1nwEURAL2kQAbkv5kKARxlSoKY6dLdSpUJCgBpCCCwB1BMAALJBlgOERUHHwCAG13KA4oAGsvJEpYeGR0TCwAXXowzIxILFicqAgJYAgUABMcOxNWKAB+DyhDRu5o5JBU9PCs4pyXTA8vX38Agoi8KABRCQBjABsZGogAHh6+6cHsFU9vP0Dg0IyIgD5nEkoZFEWBqCqWDbiKqtqcQ4nA3awLgAUPXo7hUSHOKCw+QhRWwpQAlPQjEgEDUANykW73R7PYCvcqVap1MZHSanP6A4EeRFQZGojE3O4PTJPbB4t6Ez5JFJpXaw-5ArwgsEQrDNaEDfkIpEomqEHTkRYRJDLCAAOmWSE4gpAIoGWHhDKcJFIAHpTbB3C42QCAOTUJC2lQEJhQe00W3cQ3Xc3lVisJBiKAAQVYnHk1WAUD6rmgtoIUBssgUSjRqnUKdYae4tvi9SQUYYWCwCE4KAYQlVTyQUDAogYcggVSaMdG8agrpY7C42dtautLDtDqdhBsAEYVGooAAmL0Ms0WpQBoOh8ONlBR1tuW0AIgdO9zCHzheLpfLlegwBrddYDabSmjaVjbu+xyCIT+fYHwCHHu9JpIX0YCtEhcTtfRbX-Bc-WXehVwjDdHyeNsd30A881sAsO1PMsKyrK9a3rRtmyQ59bVfSZP37UCbVtCDnVdW0rAkT1-yAA)

Comment: A small modification on this approach worked exactly as I needed it to. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could define/type `options` as a rest parameter:

```
type I18nArg = string | number;

type I18nStrings = {
  "common:abbreviatedMonths.april": [],
  "common:abbreviatedMonths.august": [],
  "common:buttons.filtersApplied": [{ "count": I18nArg,  }], 
// ...
};

type CheckedTFunction = <TKey extends keyof I18nStrings>(
  key: TKey,
  ...options: I18nStrings[TKey]
) => string;

declare const check: CheckedTFunction;

check("common:abbreviatedMonths.april") // OK
check("common:buttons.filtersApplied") // Error: Expected 2 arguments, but got 1
check("common:buttons.filtersApplied", { count: 22 }) // OK
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgjADgHYEEBOBzKBeKBnYNASySwB8okBXAWwCMI0BuAWACh3RJZEkBlQiQx4cUAN7soUAEQBjAPY0a8pAC4AhnTpoIANyLrgEACYBZFcAAWeAHTqwxADbTVUANoBdADSSZCpSoaWjr6hibmSFa26lQYVAQu7t6%20corKanRUwMAqtgBmRI5GaHgoYGCORCaJbmJ%208lSRifDI6BheUAC%20yWxSAPR9UDbD7J2sHGxc0ADClhCyANYmACoAYo2ywEQqogA8ywDSECBQEAAeRkjGIksg8nk8yALEpHgAfAAUvreuh8c%20vSGw3kYC2uVcLX4glebj%20IA87AAlDg3vhoRhxuxjPNHOodFAFEgCAS5otXLN5ktjGsNmCkJi2LJSQsPqkAmpNNo9AYjGYLNY7A5CtJkQMoAB5A7sJmU1n%20dKqTLZXI2ApFRilcqVaqiwYAUTQaHkaFcerOkE2JigACYoHi4jQIJE8B0lVAMPJgFA4NLmXK0oElTkiarCsVNRUqsZpB06gpGsBXNbbZ1dRKDkA)

Comment: This works but it is a bit cumbersome because it would require a translation function to extract the args object from the params array, so we'd run into a few issues with function binding. Thank you very much regardless.

Comment: I think the implementation can use regular optional parameter without translation function, but I might be missing something